# Laravel One to many trough belongsto and many to many (with pivot in between)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many-through, laravel-relations

I've been looking around for a fix but couldn't find it.

**The situation:**

Resources are connected to an Event, multiple resources can be connected to multiple events (many to Many).

Many Interventions are connected to only 1 single event at a time (One to Many).

**What am I trying to do?**

I'd like to make a relation between Resources and Interventions. But... of course the resources that are linked to the event must certainly be taken into account. So there may only be resources that are specific to the event that is linked to the intervention (In the screenshot you can find a part from my UML)

**In short**

I want to connect many resources to my interventions, but only those that are available on the parent Event.

I've tried HasManyTrough, wityhPivot but without a success.
I'd realy like to do it as much Laravelish as possible, so without custom queries, but if there are no other options, I'm open for everything.

[(screenshot)Order of relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx7vV.png)

Comment: are they really events, or more like models? Do you have any code prepared?

Comment: They are models, maybe indeed a bit confusing but they are not events in code, they are Events like Festivals/parades/parties.... etc

Answer (score 0):

```
In Event.php model

public function eventResource ()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EventResource','event_id','id');
}

In EventResource.php Model

public function eventDetails ()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Resource','id','resource_id');
}

In Intervention.php Model

public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Event');
}

In your Controller 

$interventions = Intervention::has('event.eventResource.eventDetails')->with('event', 'event.eventResource', 'event.eventResource.eventDetails')->get();
```

Let me know in case of any syntax error.

Please try this and let me know worked or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not exactly what I'm looking for. Because I'm working with laravel nova and I'm trying to find a way to access resources directly via 1 relation frrom interventions trough Events.

Imagine you have 1 festival, where you have your emergency first responders (your RESOURCES). aka ONE festival with MANY Resources.

Everytime they get sent out to an Intervention (for example someone who's having a stroke on the festival terrain). So there can be MANY Resources at ONE Intervention. But only the Resources that are linked on that Event can be sent out to a patient.